# Derivative of a vetor w.r.t a vector

Tags: calculus

I was watching coursera deep learning specialization of Andrew Ng, but I didn't understand something:

The activation function vector of the first layer is : $$a^{1} = \sigma(Z^{[1]})$$

So  $$a^{[1]} = \begin{align}
    \begin{bmatrix}
           \sigma(Z^{[1]}_{1}) \\
           \sigma(Z^{[1]}_{2}) \\
           \sigma(Z^{[1]}_{3}) \\
           \vdots \\
           \sigma(Z^{[1]}_{n}) 
         \end{bmatrix}
  \end{align}$$

with n the number of neurons in the first layer and $Z^{[1]}_{i}$ correspond the the ith neuron in the first layer.

$\sigma$ is the sigmoid function.

I know that  $ \frac{\partial a^{[1]}}{\partial Z^{[1]}} = \sigma(Z^{[1]})(1-\sigma(Z^{[1]}))$. But when I try to calculate it I find a matrix, because the derivative of vector w.r.t a vector gives a matrix.

Could you please  explain this to me?

Thank you.

Comment: $\sigma(Z^{[1]})$ is evidently a vector. Presumably so is $(1-\sigma(Z^{[1]}))$, though I'm unsure how $1\;-$ a vector is supposed to be interpreted. So you've got a product of two vectors. This isn't going to be a vector either. I cannot answer your question as I don't know the conventions it is using, but it is obviously using conventions that differ from the general mathematics community. Are you sure you know what they mean by the notation $\frac{\partial a^{[1]}}{\partial Z^{[1]}}$?